# PivotCache Refresh from Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, pivot-table

I am automating some Excel file creation from Access.  I need help with dynamically resetting the pivotcache for all the pivot tables.  The first set of code is me testing working code in Excel.  Now I want to translate this so that it runs from Access module.

```
Sub Update_PTSource()

With Sheets("Pivot")
    .PivotTables(1).ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=Sheets("Data").Range("data"))
End With

End Sub

Function pivot_refresh_test()

Dim pt As Variant
Dim wb, ws As Object
Dim strWBName As String
Dim strTabName As String

strWBName = "C:\Users\...\Packaged SKU.xlsb"
strTabName = "Pivot"

Set wb = GetObject(strWBName)

For Each pt In wb.Sheets(strTabName).Pivottables
    pt.ChangePivotCache wb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=wb.Sheets("Data").Range("data"))
    pt.RefreshTable
Next pt

End Function
```

I'm getting error on `pt.ChangePivotCache` line with error

> invalid procedure call or argument

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see, you've only made one simple error:

`xlDatabase` is an Excel enum, and since you're using late bindings, you don't have access to it. You can use it's integer value, 1, instead:

```
For Each pt In wb.Sheets(strTabName).Pivottables
    pt.ChangePivotCache wb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=1, SourceData:=wb.Sheets("Data").Range("data"))
    pt.RefreshTable
Next pt
```

Comment: `With Sheets("Pivot")` is also not going to fly if the `Sheets` collection isn't defined.

Answer (score 0):

I'm anal about using the least code possible when designing solutions so I found a much easier method to what I wanted to do.

My task was to update and refresh the source data of all my pivot tables.  There was one source, multiple pivot tables.  I created a dynamic named range for my source for this purpose in my template Excel book that Access was writing into.  I never save over the template I just used saveas vba to create the filled copy.

However, since I had created a named range and am modifying always the same template file with Access, I don't need to write a program to change my pivotcache.  I can just use 'Change Data Source' in Excel ribbon.  The vba code gets much easier.  It is just a variation of: ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll.  No code loops required!

The whole power of my strategy is the formula that creates my named range.  =Data!$A$5:OFFSET(Data!$A$5,COUNTA(Data!$A:$A)-1,52).  You just set the first cell of your data, and set how many columns there are for your fields, the rows are automatically adjusted.

I hope this little rant help whoever navigates here.  I've been searching a lot for good dynamic pivot table automation but most of the internet has crap info on this.